# How do I iterate over a hash in JS and return all matching results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, each, loops

I have the following piece of JS code within a function that responds to the user pressing enter (not displayed). The part of the code I am concerned with is shown:

```
       $.each(cityhash,function(key,value){
            if(value['city']== user_input) {
                $('#city').empty().append(value['city']);
                $('#state').empty().append(value['city']);
            }
```

I have the following hash:

```
cityhash =  [{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","state":"Missouri"},{"address":"0615 Mervin Rapid","city":"Tessmouth","state":"South Carolina"},{"address":"779 Elody Lock","city":"Littelside","state":"New Mexico"}]
```

As you can see, the city of Littelside appears twice in the hash. My problem is the above $.each function, only displays 1 of the 2 Littlesides. I would like to show all matches in the hash, not just 1 match.

**How can I correct my code to return all matching cities rather than just showing one city?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of the empty() calls.  You are clearing out #city/#state on each match.

```
$('#city').append(value['city']);
$('#state').append(value['state']);
```

Also, you probably want to append the state name and not the city name to the #state element

Comment: Still, if you want to empty the two elements, do it before the `$.each`.